# Window 8 App Store long running process

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a web service that will return around 360 entries from a database stored in Azure. In my `ModelView` I do an async call to retrieve the data, but the binding of the `ModelView` executes before the async call completes.

Is there a way to "wait" for the async to complete before I continue binding the `ModelView` to my view's `DataContext`, something similar to await?

```
// ModelView code

ServerSideModel.ProAmService.EntityServiceClient serviceClient = new ServerSideModel.ProAmService.EntityServiceClient();
serviceClient.GetPlayersPreviewCompleted += serviceClient_GetPlayersPreviewCompleted;
serviceClient.GetPlayersPreviewAsync(3);
```

Get's called in the constructor of the ModelView.

```
// View code

this.DataContext = _viewModel;
```

Called in the view's constructor.

Like I stated, the line `this.DataContext = _viewModel` get's called and the async function fires off without returning any data.

Answer (score 3):

You bet, it sounds to me like you may not know about ObservableCollection, a generic List that has XAML-aware events built-in. As you add or remove to this type of list, the XAML UI automatically reflects the changes. It's beautiful. Use it like this:

```
// pretend your service returns this
class MyItem { public string Name { get; set; } }

// this is a property in your view model, bind your gridview to it
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; set; }

// call this to load, it will continue to populate the UI until it is done
async System.Threading.Tasks.Task LoadAsync()
{
    var _Results = await GetItemsAsync();
    foreach (var item in _Results.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        this.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The rule of thumb for XAML development is that any type of list should be upgraded to an ObservableCollection so that it can bind easily and properly.

> Read about ObservableCollections here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx
>   Read more about XAML binding here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/xaml-binding-basics-101.html

Comment: I don't, to be quite honest. Very new to this type of stuff, prefer JavaScript. Thank you for point me in this direction, will have a look see.

Comment: Great, glad I could help; don't forget to mark the answers to your questions. Good luck.